# How to plot multiple Bar charts in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with four different values/columns for multiple time periods (in my case each week of the year). I want to plot on the sum (my 'V' variables) by time periods for the four different values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'end': ['2016-01-04', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-18', '2016-01-25'],
                    'start' : ['2015-12-28', '2016-01-04', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-18'],
                    'V1' :  [0.667, 1.229, 1.079, 1.69 ],
                    'V2' :  [5, 4, 2, 0 ],
                    'V3' :  [5, 14, 0.1, 8 ],
                    'V4' :  [2, 2, 0, 4 ],
                            })
```

Comment: Can you specify a little more what you want to plot? Do you want to plot the 'V' variables for each 'start' and 'end' time (8 bars), each 'V' for each time periods (4 bars), and how what does the "sum by time periods" look like?

Comment: How do you expect the time periods to be visualized?

Comment: @HS-nebula I want to plot the  the 'V' variables for each 'start' but the width should extend to the 'end' so four bars for each time periods.  The sums are just V1, V2, V3, and V4.

Comment: It would help to post your attempted code (not just data sample) so we can help you on any errors/undesired results.